# "COM target does not implement IDispatch" exception

Tags: c#, com, atl, idispatch

I am new to COM programming, Solution might be simple but I couldn't. 
My COM client code is working fine with early binding. Problem with late binding.

Client Code : Using .net 4.0 framework

```cs
System.Type objType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Simple_ATL.First_ATL.1", "localhost", true);
object obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
Type actualobj = obj.GetType();
actualobj.InvokeMember("AddNumbers", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance |    BindingFlags.Public, null, obj, new object[] { 10, 20 });
```

actualobj.InvokeMember throwing "COM target does not implement IDispatch" exception.

IDL file:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(C8F6E230-2672-11D3-A8A8-00105AA943DF),
    dual,
    helpstring("IFirst_ATL Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IFirst_ATL : IDispatch
{
    [id(1), helpstring("method MultipleNumbers")] HRESULT MultipleNumbers([in] long Num1, [in] long Num2, [out, retval] long *ReturnVal);
    [id(2), helpstring("method AddNumbers")] HRESULT AddNumbers([in] long Num1, [in] long Num2, [out , retval] long *ReturnVal);
};

[
     uuid(34C534A0-2671-11D3-A8A8-00105AA943DF),
     version(1.1),
     helpstring("Simple_ATL 1.1 Type Library")
]
library SIMPLE_ATLLib
{
importlib("stdole32.tlb");
importlib("stdole2.tlb");

[
    uuid(970599E0-2673-11D3-A8A8-00105AA943DF),
    version(2.1),
    helpstring(" New First_ATL Class")
]
coclass First_ATL
{
    [default] interface IFirst_ATL;
};

};
```

Please suggest me what went wrong in my code?

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: Adding more I had followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105194/how-to-call-a-dcom-object-from-c but didn't work for me..

Comment: The IDL only *promises* that you implement IDispatch, you didn't actually do so according to the error message.  That's normally pretty hard to get wrong, the ATL wizards auto-generate a lot of code.  Including this IDL, no hints there.  Inopportune editing, perhaps, somehow screwing up inheriting IDispatchImpl.   Not knowing what code to post is a strong hint that you'll have a hard time figuring out what you did wrong.  So do we.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. I found the mistake in the auto-generated code   
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CFirst_ATL)
 COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IFirst_ATL)
 **COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)** when I add it is working 
END_COM_MAP()